# Meteor: не находит шаблон при загрузке приложения на продакшене

Tags: javascript, meteor

Добавляю индикатор загрузки в приложение. Установил пакетsacha:spin.
В роутере прописал

```
Router.configure({
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    waitOn: function () {return Meteor.subscribe('tasks');}
});

Router.onBeforeAction('loading');
```

Сам шаблон loading

```
<template name="loading">
    {{> spinner}}
</template>
```

На локальной машине все работает отлично, но как только выложил на сервак, при загрузке приложения появляется сообщение:
Couldn't find a template named "loading" or "loading". Are you sure you defined it?
файл с роутером лежит в папке Lib в корне. Пробовал туда помещать шаблон loading.html, но не помогло(возможно ли что роутер грузится раньше шаблона и не видит его)
Сталкивался ли кто с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 1):

Итак неким решением проблемы стало следующее:
поместил шаблон loading из файла loading.html в файл main.html(файл loading.html удалил) и все заработало как надо.
Может кто подскажет логику происходящего?